Combined stylistic changes to single words in the bibliography while bracketed
A strange bug that seems to affect this case.
author="Conan ({\sc\tiny Doyle})",

It works but the reference jumps up to the first slot if the references are set to be sorted and there are several errors that pop up.
IEEEtran for the bibliography.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
.....\cite{...}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}\bibliography{books}
\end{document}

(i) Am I the only one getting this error with IEEEtran?
If it reproduces . . .
(ii) . . . presumably it occurs because the parentheses mess up sorting. The strange thing is that it happens only with (a) \sc and (b) font size change and (c) parentheses combined. Parentheses alone work fine. \sc alone is fine. {\Huge ...} alone is fine.
Then . . .
How does one get the parentheses to be ignored when sorting is calculated? (There is no error and numbering is unaffected in the case of any two of the three apparently.) Or is the fix something else?
